# Wordpress admin form post mandatory category

Tags: php, javascript, wordpress, admin, custom-post-type

I'm trying to find a way in WP to make a category/taxonomy mandatory for a custom post type.
Which means verifying that a category have been chosen on form submit and otherwise display an error message.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: You're welcome. What have you tried?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's some code from one of my sites to create a custom post type meta box.  It validates for a category value using jQuery, and cancels the form submission if the value doesn't exist.

```
add_action( 'load-post.php', 'gallery_meta_boxes_setup' );
add_action( 'load-post-new.php', 'gallery_meta_boxes_setup' );

/* Meta box setup function. */
function gallery_meta_boxes_setup() {
    /* Add meta boxes on the 'add_meta_boxes' hook. */
    add_action( 'add_meta_boxes', 'gallery_add_post_meta_boxes' );

}
/* Create one or more meta boxes to be displayed on the post editor screen. */
function gallery_add_post_meta_boxes() {

    add_meta_box(
        'gallery-class',            // Unique ID
        'Select Gallery',        // Title
        'gallery_class_meta_box',        // Callback function
        'cj-gallery',                    // Admin page (or post type)
        'normal',                    // Context
        'default'                    // Priority
    );
}

/* Display the post meta box. */
function gallery_class_meta_box( $object, $box ) {
?>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        jQuery(function($) {
                /********** Form Validation ***********/
            $('form').submit(function(event) {

                if ($('.categorydiv input[type="checkbox"]:checked').length == 0) {
                    alert('Please select a category!');
                    $('#ajax-loading').css('visibility', 'hidden');  // hide the ajax loading graphic
                    event.preventDefault();  // cancel form submission
                }
            })
        });
    </script>
<?php }
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for the answer. I would just add `$('input#publish').removeClass('button-primary-disabled');` after `$('#ajax-loading').css('visibility', 'hidden');`